# PyQt6/PySide6: QStackedLayout aligns the size of nested widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I created a `QStacedLayout` and nested 2 widgets in it.

However, as I understand it, if one widget is larger than the other, then `QStackedLayout` seems to be trying to equalize the size of the larger one to the smaller one.

Because of this, part of the content of the 2nd widget is "eaten" and appears only after I move the window.

How can this be fixed?

```
Large Widget Code:
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QFrame, QWidget, QLabel
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QPushButton

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

import tech


class AboutMe(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AboutMe, self).__init__()
        with open(tech.resource_path("ui\\assets\\styles\\AboutMe.qss"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            self.style = f.read()
        self.setStyleSheet(self.style)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.layout.setSpacing(3)

        self.text = QLabel("text "*800)
        self.text.setWordWrap(True)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


class AboutPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AboutPage, self).__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(3)

        self.aboutme = AboutMe()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.aboutme)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Main Widget Code:

```
class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, bot, parent):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()

        self.page_layout = QStackedLayout()
        self.page_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.page_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(3)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.main_page = MainPage(bot)
        self.about_page = AboutPage()
        self.page_layout.addWidget(self.main_page)
        self.page_layout.addWidget(self.about_page)
        self.page_layout.setCurrentIndex(0)

        self.bar = CustomBar(parent)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.bar)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.page_layout)

        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
```

Result:
First Widget:

[image]

Second (larger):

[image]

When I switched to at least a pixel:

[image]

Comment: 1. Please try to always provide a [mre] (many parts of your code are probably unnecessary to reproduce the issue, so they should not be included, but if they were, we couldn't reproduce it anyway because you're using classes we know nothing about); 2. The issue is most probably caused by [known issues of Qt layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues); 3. QStackedLayout always uses the biggest minimum size hint of its pages and eventually makes "smaller" widgets grow to that size, not the opposite.

Comment: @musicamante, I apologize for the code, I did not think about how to remove the deprivation.

I tested the same with other widgets and found out that this problem is only with QLabel.

Comment: Yes, as the docs explain, it's a specific issue of rich text (or, to be precise, word wrapping) when set on labels. There's little you can do about it, as it's a known issue that will probably be *never* fixed due to the way layout managers work. If you do need a page with so much text, it would be better to put it in a QTextEdit instead.

Comment: @musicamante, fixed it with `some_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)`.

Comment: Be aware that you will still have the problem of text that becomes partially hidden, caused by the issue above, which could happen for very long text or specific combinations of very short or very long words (it depends on how the QTextLayout creates lines, based on the font metrics). As said, for long texts, it's usually better to use a scroll area, like a QTextEdit in read only mode.